# Serialize enum as int

Tags: .net, enums, xml-serialization

I am looking to return the following class through a web service, which includes an enum type as one of its members.

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("GeoCoordinate")]
public class GeoCoordinate
{
    public enum AccuracyLevel
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Country = 1,
        Region = 2,
        SubRegion = 3,
        Town = 4,
        PostalCode = 5,
        Street = 6,
        Intersection = 7,
        Address = 8,
        Premise = 9
    }

    private AccuracyLevel _accuracy;

    // ... more members


    public AccuracyLevel Accuracy
    {
        get { return _accuracy; } 
        set { _accuracy = value;}
    }
}
```

This works correctly, but will return a result in the form of:

```
<!-- ... -->
<Accuracy>Unknown or Country or Region or SubRegion or Town or 
  PostalCode or Street or Intersection or Address or Premise</Accuracy>
<!-- ... -->
```

Instead of a string that represents the enum, I would like it to simply return an integer.  Can this be done without changing the type of `GeoCoordinate.Accuracy`?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it is a hack, I deemed using [`XmlEnumAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlenumattribute.aspx) on each of the enum members to be most pallatable in this case.  If this enum were much larger, it would probably be better to use `XmlIgnore` on the Accuracy property, and add an additional int property to the class as described in another answer to this question.

Usng `XmlEnumAttribute` means that only the enum itself needs to be modified, and will xml serialize like an int wherever it is used.

```
    public enum AccuracyLevel
    {
        [XmlEnum("0")] Unknown = 0,
        [XmlEnum("1")] Country = 1,
        [XmlEnum("2")] Region = 2,
        [XmlEnum("3")] SubRegion = 3,
        [XmlEnum("4")] Town = 4,
        [XmlEnum("5")] PostalCode = 5,
        [XmlEnum("6")] Street = 6,
        [XmlEnum("7")] Intersection = 7,
        [XmlEnum("8")] Address = 8,
        [XmlEnum("9")] Premise = 9
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this over Saunderses answer

Comment: And what about Flag Enums? Is it possible to serialize flag combinations using this method?

Comment: @fibriZo no, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll need to use `[XmlIgnore]` on the enum, and create a second property which returns the integer value:

```
[XmlRoot("GeoCoordinate")]
public class GeoCoordinate
{
    public enum AccuracyLevel
    {
        Unknown = 0,
        Country = 1,
        Region = 2,
        SubRegion = 3,
        Town = 4,
        PostalCode = 5,
        Street = 6,
        Intersection = 7,
        Address = 8,
        Premise = 9
    }

    private AccuracyLevel _accuracy;

    // ... more members


    [XmlIgnore]
    public AccuracyLevel Accuracy
    {
        get { return _accuracy; } 
        set { _accuracy = value;}
    }

    [XmlElement("AccuracyLevel")]
    public int AccuracyLevelInt
    {
        get {return (int) AccuracyLevel;}
        set {AccuracyLevel = (AccuracyLevel) value;}
    }
}
```

Note that `[Serializable]` is not used by the XML Serializer.

Also, note that the `AccuracyLevelInt` property is probably implemented incorrectly. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: This would work, but I was hoping to avoid creating another property (perhaps through an Xml attribute on GeoCoordinate.Accurate, but it seems like this doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the enum with `[Serializable]` or `[DataContract]`. There are some differences between the two attributes, make sure you check it out ([this blog post](http://dotnet.org.za/hiltong/pages/windows-communication-foundation-tutorial-part-2-datacontract-vs-serializable.aspx) may help with that). And mark the individual enum items with `[EnumMember]`. I have never checked what the enum looks like in transit, but doing this will ensure that it arrives at the other end, and will also ensure that it gets picked up if you generate a client side proxy.

Comment: None of these options seem to change the manner in which this field is serialized.

Comment: Yeah, i think that when it comes to WCF it makes no difference, but it does if you are serializing to XML? I would welcome anyone giving a simple bullet explanation of the differences.