# Tombstone wp7 how save Enum... and other unkwon object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

When I save a variable that containing an Enum type in wp7 (C#) I receive an Exception, the meaning is that enum is a not known type so the system cannot serialize.

for example

```
public enum videoType:int {
       LongVideo=1,
      ShortVideo }

or

public enum video
{

       LongVideo,ShortVideo
}


 _videoType = videoType.ShortVideo 


PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["myType"]
```

someone tell me to use Datacontract and data member but seems not available in wp7

so how save a enum type?

Comment: Can you share the actual code snippet and error message? If you try to save a variable to State that holds an enum value, it should hold the actual integer value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to save the Enum Value as integer and reset to correct Enum value from the integer after the page gets activated.

[Read back the saved integer value and set the correct enum value. Lookup Enum.Parse/Enum.TryParse]

Also you can have a look at the EnumValueToDescription Converter attribute implemented by Josh Smith in his article here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFJoshSmith.aspx?msg=3766336 [WPF]

http://www.michaelsnow.com/2010/12/25/how-to-convert-an-enum-to-its-string-value/

Comment: sorry what you mean with reset the correct value after activation?

Answer (score 0):

DataContract and DataMember most definitely *are* available in all versions of WP7.

You do not need to specify int as the ancestor type because int is the default ancestor type.

```
public enum videoType  
{
  LongVideo = 1,
  ShortVideo, 
}
```

Since you can convert int to an int-based enum with simple cast, I suggest casting as int to save and casting back to your enum to load.

Answer (score 0):

See the answers at: [How do I serialize an enum value as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int)