# How to serialize DayOfWeek to have its number?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, serialization, dayofweek

I have a class that has a property with data type DayOfWeek, I need to serialize it into XML, when I'm serializing it the DayOfWeek is serialized by its name, like 'Monday' and etc. I need it's related value
Here is my Class:

```
public class myClass
{
 [XmlAttribute("DayOfWeek")]
 public DayOfWeek myDay;
}
```

This is the Serialized string:

```
<myClass DayOfWeek="Monday" />
<myClass DayOfWeek="Friday" />
```

my desire format should be something like this:

```
   <myClass DayOfWeek="1" />
   <myClass DayOfWeek="5" />
```

I cannot use get and set. I think that there should be an attribute for doing that.
Thank you for your help. :)

here is my serializer method

```
 public static SqlXml Serialize<T>(T dataObject, string defaultNamespace = DefaultNamespace)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), defaultNamespace);
            var wr = new StringWriter();
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

            using (var responseWriter = XmlWriter.Create(wr, settings))
            {
                if (responseWriter != null)
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(responseWriter, dataObject);
            }
            using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(wr.ToString())))
            {
                return new SqlXml(xmlReader);
            }
        }
```

this method is working without any issue.

Comment: `Here is my Class:` Your class is not compilable.

Comment: Most probably you use XmlSerializer, but why don't you include the code about how you serialize it?

Comment: Yes I'm using XmlSerializer. I am editing the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok .... this is my final ( and not the best) solution!

I just created another enum ...

```
[Serializable]
public enum DayOfWeekEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "0")]
    Sunday = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "1")]
    Monday = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "2")]
    Tuesday = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "3")]
    Wednesday = 3,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "4")]
    Thursday = 4,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "5")]
    Friday = 5,

    [EnumMember]
    [XmlEnum(Name = "6")]
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[XmlIgnore]
```

And then create a property that returns its int value. (Though I'll be happy to find out there's a better built-in way.)

For more information see [How do I serialize an enum value as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int) .

Comment: Maybe that is the best way