# How to parse enum string & value from XML model to object

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, enums, xml-parsing

Problem: How to parse enum string & value from XML model to object.

Error: Cannot parse enum value from XML to object model.

I tried to parse only enum value, but cannot parse to model. I tried some solutions but I still faced issue, please help to advise! Thanks for your support!

- Enum:

  ```
  public enum DocumentType
  {
      DocumentType_A = 0,
      DocumentType_B = 1,
      DocumentType_C = 2
  }
  ```
- XML:

  [image]

Comment: Post the XML as _text_, post the code you used to deserialize. Post the target C# class.

Comment: i guess that the number is from something like an external API? you could work around that using a separated property of the type `int` and some `XmlIgnore` property that just reads/writes to that field essentially parsing by hand.

Comment: @X39 I want to read value from XML file. How to use XmlIgnore to read value in this case? Please share some example. Thank you!

Comment: @HuuHa would be nice to know what exactly you are doing, are you just reading the document by hand or are you serializing it into some object?

provide some minimum-viable-example and the correct answer should be fairly close

Comment: How to parse document type in this deserialize method below:
Document overview = (Document)reader.Deserialize(file);
public class Document
    {
                public long DocumentId { get; set; }
                public DocumentType Type{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: Not very readable, [edit] your question.

Comment: @X39: See my comment.

Comment: @HuuHa it still is not really very clear what you are doing. Could you edit the original question to at least match the code you use? also check out this as it might be your solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506368/how-do-i-serialize-an-enum-value-as-an-int

Comment: @X39 That's great! It worked for me. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the node from the XML and then parse it to an enum.

```
const string str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Document><DocumentId>1</DocumentId><Attachment></Attachment><Metadata><DocumentType>0</DocumentType></Metadata></Document>";
var xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(str);

var node = xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Document/Metadata/DocumentType").InnerText;
DocumentType currentEnum = (DocumentType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DocumentType), node);
int currentEnumId = (int)currentEnum;
```

UPDATE based on comments - Deserialize xml to object with enums

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
<DocumentId>1</DocumentId>
<Attachment></Attachment>
<Metadata>
    <DocumentType>1</DocumentType>
</Metadata>
</Document>
```

Models

```
    public class Document 
    { 
        public long DocumentId { get; set; } 

        public Metadata Metadata { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Metadata
    {

        public string DocumentType  { get; set; } 

        public DocumentType Type 
        {
            get
            {
                return (DocumentType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DocumentType), DocumentType);
            }
        }

    }

    public enum DocumentType 
    { 
        DocumentType_A = 0, 
        DocumentType_B = 1, 
        DocumentType_C = 2 
    };
```

Converting XML to Object:

```
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document)); 
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("/Users/brunomartinspro/Desktop/myxml.xml")) 
    { 
        Document document = (Document)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
        var mySuperType = document.Metadata.Type; 
    }
```

Comment: That would do `Enum.Parse("0")`

Comment: How to parse document type in this deserialize method below:
Document overview = (Document)reader.Deserialize(file);
public class Document
    {
                public long DocumentId { get; set; }
                public DocumentType Type{ get; set; }
    }

Comment: @bommelding but you still get the enum :)

Comment: @BrunoMartinsPro:Do you have any solution/idea for this case?

Comment: @HuuHa give me 10 minutes and I will update my answer to do that :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @HuuHa no problem, I updated the answer without the Attachments property for simplicity of this scope, have fun! ;)

Comment: @HuuHa if this solved your problem please mark it as the correct answer :)