# XMLSerializer.Serialize - serializing valid enum value - Instance validation error: 'XXX' is not a valid value for

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a strange problem with XMLSerializer.Serialize - when serializing an object with a valid enum valie (e.g. Item911), I receive an InvalidOperationException with error message "There was an error generating the XML document."

But: The enum value seems valid, it is in the generated enum from the contract (enum has been created automatically via xsd.exe)

The stack trace points me to the call of **System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize**, the rest is generated code from microsoft:

```
<Exception
  Type=System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=Instance validation error: '911' is not a valid value for YYY.
  Source=Microsoft.GeneratedCode>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[    
     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSonstigeFolgeeingabe.Write61_DienststelleMenge(DienststelleMenge v)
     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSonstigeFolgeeingabe.Write65_Aktenzeichen(String n, String ns, Aktenzeichen o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSonstigeFolgeeingabe.Write140_SonstigeFolgeeingabe(String n, String ns, SonstigeFolgeeingabe o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
     at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterSonstigeFolgeeingabe.Write141_SonstigeFolgeeingabe(Object o)
  ]]>
  </StackTrace>
</Exception>
```

It only occurs in production (release compiled), when I try to debug it the code (even with Data where it fails in production), it works.

Additional context:

- the data is for a payload of a webservice call
- the classes are generated via xsd.exe from xsd-files and not manipulated
- I wasn't able to reproduce the bug

I tried to reproduce the bug locally and at the customer (working in a debug environment with mocked webservices), but I wasn't able to reproduce the bug.

Comment: You don't share a [mcve] so it's hard to say for sure what your problem is, but `XmlSerializer` does not support serializing & deserializing numeric values as enums.  Instead it only supports serializing & deserializing enum **names**.  If you want to deserialize the value, see [How do I serialize an enum value as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/506368).  But to give a definite answer we will need likely need more details, ideally a [mcve], specifically a c# data model and XML that generate the exception.

Comment: Or is the exception getting thrown from with the the `XmlSerializer` constructor?

Comment: I made progress - I found a blog post [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/how-to-debug-into-a-net-xmlserializer-generated-assembly) about how to generate/find the generated assemblies used for serialization. (In another post [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/changing-where-xmlserializer-outputs-temporary-assemblies) is also a way to configure the path of these files )

The production environment is currently configured that every 24h the windows service is restarted - so maybe the temporary assembly is the regenerated and the error no longer occurres?